# Can I use Ubuntu on my Mac to recover a FAT32 drive?

Tags: fat32

I installed a game on my PS3 which is formatted for FAT32 and it corrupted the drive. (The same game did the same thing on another PS3. Rats.) I need to recover the drive but am a Mac user. Can I install Ubuntu on my (older) (Intel 2.8 Ghz dual from 2007) Mac and use a disk utility in Ubuntu to attempt to recover the drive? Does Ubuntu work with FAT32 drives? I don't have access to a Windows machine, so that's out.

Thanks for the info.

Binky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the package dosfstools

```
sudo apt-get install dosfstools
```

and run the command (change to suite your partition number and device letter)

```
sudo dosfsck -r /dev/sdb1
```

repeatedly until there are no more errors.

Comment: Thanks, ubfan1; this is zactly what I needed! I feel hopeful that this is gonna bring my drive back, assuming it's not totally hosed! I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: Well, nuts; I'm too new to upvote you yet. Moreover, I don't know anything about Ubuntu yet, so it'd be a strain to post enough to earn myself enough rep to be able to upvote you. Argh. Please let's pretend I upvoted you. (banging head on desk)

Comment: Don't worry about the upvote, but you should be able to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I'm not seeing an "accepted" button anywhere. Would love to be able to close the question. I'm running Safari on an iPad. If a friendly admin is able to do it for me, I'd be grateful. I swear I've scrolled all over the page, and don't see it anywhere.

Comment: I clicked a star, and it turned into a check mark. Perhaps that did the trick?

Comment: The accept button is a circled checkmark below the number and below the down-vote tick, next to the answer. See http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Comment: It's actually a circled star; it turns into a check mark after it's clicked. It's not intuitive, but it did the job!

Comment: I hope this means the question is now closed so that people won't feel the need to read the question in an attempt to help out?

Comment: The circled star is just a "favorites" button on the question.  The acceptance circled checkmark is on the answer, and when selected, turns green. So no, the question is still "open" = "no ans accepted yet".

Comment: Alright. I selected the check mark I received when I tapped the star. It's now green. That wasn't so very convoluted!